# Sending mail using PHP (to the one that puts the email in the EMAIL INPUT)

Tags: php

I want to know how can , (for exemple my friend ) sends email to himself using the Php mail() function ive created.I give him the website ,he puts the email and a message ( inside the form ive created) then he is pressing submit button, but im the one getting the email not him.Im new to Programing.Ty

Comment: Yes its possible. And your question is to broad. You can do it many ways.

Comment: It sound like the to parameter is your email not they guys email

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$email = "youremailaddress";
$yoursubject="Something ...";
$yourmessage="Something else...";    
mail($email, $yoursubject, $yourmessage);
```